# How to determine which processor has the highest performance

Tags: performance, cpu, clock, instruction-set

The following conditions exist.

> Consider three diff erent processors P1, P2, and P3 executing the same
> instruction set.  P1 has a 3 GHz clock rate and a CPI of 1.5.  P2 has
> a
> 2.5 GHz clock rate and a CPI of 1.0.  P3 has a 4.0 GHz clock rate and has a CPI of 2.2.

And the question is

> Which processor has the highest performance when executing the same program?

I have learned to compare cpu execution when comparing computer performance.

However, since `cpu execution time = CPI * instruction set * 1/clock rate`, the size of the instruction set cannot be known only with the conditions in the above problem, I thought that the performance between processors could not be compared.

I looked for other issues similar to this one, and the issue is `Which processor has the highest performance expressed in instructions per second?` We compared the performance between processors under the condition of instructions per second as shown.

So what I want to know is whether it is possible to compare performance between processors without any special conditions. (Isn't the given problem wrong?) If possible, I wonder how they can be compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, since `cpu execution time = CPI * instruction set * 1/clock rate`, the size of the instruction set cannot be known only with the conditions in the above problem, I thought that the performance between processors could not be compared.

For that formula; I'd assume that `instruction set` reflects how many instructions are needed to do the same work. E.g. if one instruction set can do a multiply in one instruction it might have `instruction set = 1`, and if another instruction set needs 20 instructions to do one multiply then it might have `instruction set = 20` because you need 20 times as many instructions to get the same work done.

For your homework (3 processors that all execute the same instruction set), `instruction set` is irrelevant - they all take the same number of instructions to get any amount of work done. With this in mind you can just do `performance = clock rate / CPI`. More specifically:

```
P1 = 3 GHz / 1.5 = 2,000,000,000
P2 = 2.5 GHz / 1.0 = 2,500,000,000
P3 = 4 GHz / 2.2 = 1,818,181,818
```

Of course the homework is extremely over-simplified - stalls (time CPU spends doing nothing while waiting for things like cache misses and instruction fetch after a branch misprediction, etc) tend to have a larger impact on performance than clock speed or "theoretical maximum CPI"; and "measured CPI in practice" depends which specific instructions are used (and can never be a single number like "1.5 CPI" for all programs). In other words, in practice, it's easy to have a situation where a CPU is fastest for one program but slowest for another program.